# Haskell writeFile

Tags: haskell, types, io

Beginner. Got a module called HHtml outputting this:

```
  setDoc = "<!DOCTYPE = <html><head>"
  setTitle = "<title>" ++ htmlTitle generator ++ "</title>"
  setHeader = "<header>" ++ htmlHeader generator ++ "</header>"
  setMeta = "<meta>" ++ htmlMeta generator ++ "</meta></head>"
  setBody = "<body>" ++ htmlBody generator ++ "</body>"
  setFooter = "<footer>" ++ htmlFooter generator ++ "</footer>"
  setEOF = "</html>"

  setHTML = [setDoc, setTitle, setHeader, setMeta, setBody, setFooter, setEOF]
```

main file:

```
import HHtml
import System.IO

main = do
  let content = mapM_ putStrLn setHTML
  writeFile "index.html" content
```

Now however I look at it I keep getting the `Couldn't match type IO() with [Char]` or any variant for that matter. I understand the error message, but I am getting so confused about fixing it. Thanks for the pointers!

Comment: The fix depends on what you're trying to achieve. What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: outputting (writeFile) html created by using `mapM_` over list `setHTML`. The setDoc, setTitle etc are just placeholders

Comment: What are you using `mapM_` for?

Comment: Because eventually the values in the list will be IO intake

Comment: just to make sure - if you're using this for production make sure you either control the input or do some escaping to avoid JS-injections

Comment: @epsilonhalbe: I am a beginner in Haskell, but starting on pre-production code will help me use the info from all the books (LYAH, RWH, Graham Hutton etc). I plan on making it way more flexible and use HTML5/JS templating and Haskell to insert code, so you comment is very valuable to me. Thank you!

Comment: @chi: thanks for pitching in. I read it, but to me that is not directly related. I am aware of readFile/writeFile and how to operate. Jon Purdy came with a perfect answer with merely using 'unlines', rather than run it through a monadic function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mapM_ putStrLn setHTML` is an action of type `IO ()`, which you’re assigning to a name `content` with a `let` statement. When executed, this action would *print* each line of `setHTML`, returning nothing. You could execute this action by writing something like this:

```
main = do
  let content = mapM_ putStrLn setHTML
  content
```

Without the variable, this is just:

```
main = mapM_ putStrLn setHTML
```

But `content` is an opaque value—the only things you can do with it are *execute* it from `main`, join it up to other `IO` actions with `>>=` (or `do` notation), and store it in a data structure (which isn’t necessary here). In particular, it doesn’t “store” the content of the page, it merely describes to the runtime how it should print that content. And anyway there’s the type mismatch you noticed: `writeFile` accepts a `String`, a.k.a. `[Char]`, which is obviously not an `IO ()`.

But since you apparently want to use `writeFile` to write each line of `setHTML` to a file, instead of standard output, you don’t want an action that will print the lines—you want the lines themselves, joined together with newlines. There are a few possible ways to do that, depending on how you’d like to extend this code.

One way is to use the `unlines :: [String] -> String` function to concatenate the lines together with newlines, then use `writeFile` to write the resulting `String` to `"index.html"`:

```
main = writeFile "index.html" (unlines setHTML)
```

If you want to place the concatenated content in a variable, you can of course do that:

```
main = do
  let content = unlines setHTML
  writeFile "index.html" content
```

(Indeed you might move the `unlines` call into the definition of `setHTML` if you don’t need `setHTML` to be a `[String]`.)

Now `writeFile` will accept `content` because it’s a `String` value, not an `IO ()` action. This is a nice approach because it keeps the logic of *building* the page pure, and only uses `IO` as needed to actually *write* the page.

Alternatively, you can take a more imperative approach, staying in `IO`. Then a good function to use is `withFile` (from `System.IO`), which has the following type:

```
FilePath -> IOMode -> (Handle -> IO r) -> IO r
```

It takes a `FilePath` to open, an `IOMode` (e.g. `ReadMode` or `WriteMode`) to indicate whether you’ll be reading from or writing to the handle, and a *function* that accepts the handle and does some `IO` and returns a result of some type `r`; it returns an `IO` action that opens the file, runs your function, automatically ensures the file is closed (even if an exception was thrown), and returns the result.

Then you would use `mapM_` in a similar way to how you already have, to print each line to that handle—for that, there’s `hPutStrLn :: Handle -> String -> IO ()` which writes to a particular handle, instead of `putStrLn` which writes to standard output. A compact version:

```
main = withFile "index.html" WriteMode $ \file -> do
  mapM_ (hPutStrLn file) setHTML
```

Or a more verbose version if you don’t like the look of the lambda:

```
main = withFile "index.html" WriteMode writeContents
  where writeContents file = mapM_ (hPutStrLn file) setHTML
```